# Is there a way to ignore files only but not folders?

Tags: git

I have a folder with lots of subfolders that contain lots of different file types. I want particular file types to be added to git repository. And I don’t want to add any other file types. I’ looking for solutions that will work for every folder structure.

Thus I’m trying to exclude all the files containing in the folder structure except of particular patterns.
The problem is, as I understand, git doesn’t look into ignored folders.

For instance, let's say I want to place to git *.docx and ignore the rest of files.
Could anybody say what .gitignore should be in this case?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: @zhekaus This smells a bit like an XY problem. What is it that you're *really* trying to achieve?

Comment: @Biffen
I have a folder with lots of subfolders that contain lots of different file types. I want particular file types to be placed to git repository. And I don’t want to place to git any other file types. I’ looking gor solutions that will work for every folder structure.

For instance I want to place to git *.docx and leave the rest of files.
What .gitignore could be in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Use '!' before the path of file in .gitignore

Ignore this folder

```
ProjectNameFolder/bin/*
```

But not these files

```
!ProjectNameFolder/bin/project.dll
!*/bin/project.dll
```

Comment: Folder structure is dynamic. I know nothing about subfolders.

Comment: If you check the default file created by git, you can see all the way to ignore and include files.

Comment: Pardon? What is a default .gitignore? Where can I get it?

Comment: when you first time pull repository from server, you will receive a default file.

Comment: No, I'm not. I have no preconfigured default .gitignore in my installation.

Comment: @Lali That's not true. Git repositories do *not* come with a ‘default’ `.gitignore`. If you get one when you clone/pull then someone must have *manually* added it to the remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `.gitignore` file into each folder you want to track but do not want to track files inside it. Contents of .gitignore should be:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

In this case all the files inside those folder will be ignored but folders themselves will be tracked by git.
The only drawback is that .gitignore files will also be tracked.

Comment: It demands to remember to put .gitignore to each new folder. It isn’t convenient. The folder structure is changing very often.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude everything, then unexclude the files you do want.

```
*.*
!*.docx
```

eg with the dir structure:

```
|-- a
|   |-- aa
|   |   |-- asd.docx
|   |   `-- sef.fvd
|   |-- ab
|   |-- ferfe.docx
|   `-- refdv.dsfv
|-- b
|   |-- a
|   |   |-- fsef.egrd
|   |   `-- sree.docx
|   |-- eser.docx
|   `-- fefsd.dfv
|-- bhy.vc
|-- rgt.d
|-- rsh.vdf
|-- sdf.nh
`-- sfsfd.docx
```

Adding everything gives:

```
$/tmp/exc: git add .
$/tmp/exc: git status
On branch master

Initial commit


Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

new file:   a/aa/asd.docx
new file:   a/ferfe.docx
new file:   b/a/sree.docx
new file:   b/eser.docx
new file:   sfsfd.docx
```